# Mongodb não retorna consulta corretamente

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, mongodb

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

class ConectaMongodb:

    def conecta(self):

        client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
        db = client.starwars_api
        return db

    def search_name(self, name):   

        c = ConectaMongodb()
        conn = c.conecta()

        posts = conn.planetas

        try:
            name_posts = posts.find({'name': name.title()})
            for post in name_posts:
                print('Id: {0} \nNome: {1} \nClima: {2} \nTerreno: {3} \nAparições em filmes: {4} vezes \n'
                    .format(post['_id'], post['name'], post['climate'], post['terrain'], post['counter']))    

        except:
            print('Nenhum planeta foi encontrado.')
```

Quando executo o método da seguinte forma:

```
conn = ConectaMongodb()
conn.conecta()
conn.search_name('Tatooine')
```

Meu retorno é:

Id: 5cdceb8732e8b889be669fc4
Nome: Tatooine
Clima: arid
Terreno: desert
Aparições em filmes: 5 vezes

Porém quando o método recebe um valor que era para dar erro, não retorna nada:

```
conn = ConectaMongodb()
conn.conecta()
conn.search_name('Tatone')
```

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de usar

`except:
     print('Nenhum planeta foi encontrado.')`

usa

`except ValueError:
     print('Nenhum planeta foi encontrado.')`

Comment: o problema ainda persiste

Comment: Ele não lhe dá nenhum erro quando não encontra?